# Dynamically check for form completion within a div

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="panel-title>
    <span class="fa fa-caret-right" ng-if="!showGeneral"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-caret-down" ng-if="showGeneral"></span>
  </div>
  <label>GENERAL</label>
  <div ng-if="generalFormName.$valid" class="pull-right">
     <i class="fa fa-check" style="color:#4cc94c;font-size:large;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse" ng-if="showGeneral">
    <general></general>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
<form name="generalFormName" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" class="form-control align" required  ng-model="infor.name" />
</form>
</div>
```

The directive `general` is another `html`. When the required fields in that form are filled in by the user I need a check mark to displayed to the right of the label. I do not have any button to submit and send the form data and then check for validation. I just need a check mark when `formname.$valid`. I added an `ng-if` but for some reason I am not able to get it.

Can someone help me out on this? Would be of great help .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add html with form tag.

Comment: anything in the console

Comment: Nope.. I tried to print `{{generalFormName.$invalid}} beside the label and do not get either a true or false value. I guess I am missing out on the scope somewher @RIYAJKHAN

Answer (score 0):

A form in Angular makes its validation state available *through its name* and only to its *scope and the descendant scopes*. Currently the `<general>` directive is outside the form's scope, so it cannot access the validation data. The simplest solution is to reposition the form to enclose both the input(s) and the `<general>` directive:

```
<form name="generalFormName" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <div class="well">
        ...
        <general></general>
        ...
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control align" required ng-model="infor.name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If the `<form>` must absolutely stay where it is, you can wrap it with an `ng-form` and use the `ng-form`'s validity in `<general>`:

```
<div ng-form="ngFormName">
    <div class="well">
        ...
        <general valid="ngFormName.$valid"></general>
        ...
    </div>

    <div>
        <form name="generalFormName" novalidate autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" class="form-control align" required ng-model="infor.name" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The validity of the inner `generalFormName` affects the validity of the wrapper `ngFormName`.

If neither solution works (I don't see a reason why), you can always create a directive that publishes the validity of its adjacent form to a variable in the parent scope. Using variables in the parent scope is tricky, and I believe the previous solutions should be adequate, so I will not go in details. Instead of a variable, it could invoke a callback function - expect less surprises.

Comment: I haven' tried this but how I got this working is by providing an alias for the controller being used in the page (ctrller) and added the condition before the directive as `ng-if="ctrller.generalFormName.$valid"` . I got it working using this.